# Why eval() isn't working here to deserialize such a simple JSON object?

Tags: json, eval, javascript

I am trying to use eval() function to deserialize this JSON text by using eval function.

```
var personJSON = {
  "FirstName": "Burak",
  "LastName": "Ozdogan",
  "Id": "001",
  "Department": "Information Technologies"
};

var personBurakOzdogan = eval('(' + personJSON + ')');
```

But I am getting this error:

```
*Microsoft JScript compilation error: Expected ']'*
```

Is there something that I skip which I cannot catch?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is not JSON text. It is already a JSON object. So you don't need to use `eval` at all. You can directly access and manipulate its properties:

```
alert(personJSON.FirstName);
```

Comment: Idiot me! Thanks Darin! :)
I have enclosed that within ' ' and eval worked.

Comment: @burak, I think you're missing the point. Since you have it in object-literal form, there's no point in getting it in JSON...

Comment: Actually this is why I am doing this practice. I had a problem to understand the exact difference between a JSON object and an onbect defined with Object-Literal feature of JavaScript. Thank you Darin once again.

Answer (score 3):

Try to check if your personJSON is a wrapper that CONTAINS the real json. For example, try to write:

```
var person = eval('(' + personJSON.Person + ')')
```

where `Person` is the class serialized by the service.

OR

try this:

```
var person = eval('(' + personJSON.GetPersonResult + ')')
```

where `GetPerson` is the method name in the service, plus `Result`.

Answer (score 2):

you are not dealing with a string, but with a json object. You are trying to evaluate a json object as string to create a json object.

```
var personJSON =
  '{"FirstName":"Burak","LastName":"Ozdogan","Id":"001","Department":"Information Technologies"}';

var personBurakOzdogan = eval('(' + personJSON + ')');
```

this should work, although it doesn't make to much sense. this makes more sense:

```
var personBurakOzdogan = {
  "FirstName": "Burak",
  "LastName": "Ozdogan",
  "Id": "001",
  "Department": "Information Technologies"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass to the variable a string type as the code seen below:

```
var personJSON = '{"FirstName":"Burak","LastName":"Ozdogan","Id":"001","Department":"Information Technologies"}';
```